# Can't monkeypatch functions on python + pytest

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I need to monkeypatch some functions on a project I am writing tests for, but before it I created a simple project to try it out (it basically uses requests.get to call the ipify API to get my public IP, and I am trying to monkey patch the requests.get function OR the function on my own code that calls requests.get, in order to return a fixed value - "0.0.0.0" in this case).

The project structure looks like this:

- root directory

  - ipify_api (my package)

    - methods.py (here I have the function that return the public IP returned by the API)
    - helpers.py (here I have the function that call the API and returns the response)
  - tests

    - test_ipify.py

The project code is the following:

**ipify_api/helpers.py**

```py
from requests import get

def request_ipify_api():
    r = get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=raw")
    return r
```

**ipify_api/methods.py**

```py
from .helpers import *

def get_public_ip() -> str:
    r = request_ipify_api()
    return r.text
```

**tests/test_ipify.py**

```py
import requests
import ipify_api
# import ipify_api.helpers

class FakeResponse:
    text: str

class TestIpifyAPI:
    @staticmethod
    def __get_fake_response():
        r = FakeResponse()
        r.text = "0.0.0.0"
        return r

    def test_get_public_ip(self, monkeypatch):
        """Calling methods.get_public_ip() should return 0.0.0.0
        """
        # monkeypatch.setattr(ipify_api.helpers, "request_ipify_api", self.__get_fake_response)
        monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "get", self.__get_fake_response)
        assert ipify_api.get_public_ip() == "0.0.0.0"
```

The problem is the real function keeps being called, so I do not get the expected "0.0.0.0" result, but my real IP instead (because the real requests.get get called). Patching the ipify_api.helpers.request_ipify_api() function of my own gives the same result.

As far as I understand, I am doing what the pytest documentation states for monkey patching functions: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#simple-example-monkeypatching-functions

Comment: Patch where you use it, not where it comes from. In your case you have to patch `ipify.get` instead of `requests.get`.

Comment: @KlausD. That's it, working as intended now, thanks!